# Access to Excel controls

Tags: c#, excel, controls, vsto

Is there a way to access to any controls like

[image: controls like those]

those in a Excel sheet from C# (vsto add-in)?

In VBA you can access them without any troubly with a direct call like you do in a winform application. But in C# I didn't found any possibilities.

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no way, you need to use winforms controls in C#.

VBA controls can only be used in VBA.